# Unable to uncheck some SDK Update Sites in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to uncheck any of the update sites that contain Images witch I do not require. I can only uncheck the first one (Android Repository). Does anybody know why this is the case? Is this a bug in Android Studio?

Thank you

[image: Android Studio Settings screenshot]

Comment: have you tried after restarting studio.

Comment: yes, I have tried it after restarting Android Studio and also after updating Android Studio to the latest version.

Comment: I'm already with the same problem, AS 2.3.3 Any news?

Comment: No, the problem remains